# Eureka - StepperRow - How do I only show the integer number on label

Tags: swift, label, eureka-forms

I would like to show only Integer numbers on the StepperRow.
That is what my initialisation looks like:

```
StepperRow()
{
     $0.title = "Integer"
     $0.tag = "integer"
     $0.value = 0      
}.cellSetup
{ cell, row in
     cell.stepper.minimumValue = 0
}
```

It looks like this now:

[image: StepperRow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onChange` callback to update your label and force the text of the cell to have `integer` Value

This is the code

```
<<< StepperRow().cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                    row.title = "Integer"
                    row.tag = "integer"
                    row.value = 0
                    cell.valueLabel.text = "\(Int(row.value!))"
                }).cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                    if(row.value != nil)
                    {
                    cell.valueLabel.text = "\(Int(row.value!))"
                    }
                }).onChange({ (row) in
                    if(row.value != nil)
                    {
                        row.cell.valueLabel.text = "\(Int(row.value!))"
                    }
                })
```

It works, was tested

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: I glad, @sidetrax best regards, and happy coding